# How to get only the first match of a RegEx (UiPath Studio RegEx Based Extractor)

Tags: regex, ocr, uipath, uipath-studio, pdf-extraction

I have the following text that I extracted from a PDF using UiPath Studio's OCR. It's the same block of text repeated 3 times due to it being the original, duplicate & triplicate of the same PDF page.

```
Os bens/serviços foram colocados à disposição do adquirente em 2020-04-16 * Data/Hora início de transporte: 2020-04-16 às 11:52

Total Líquido               500,00
Total de Descontos 500,00         
Desconto Documento                
Total de IVA                115,00
Total do Documento (EUR)    615,00

IVA      Incidência   Valor do IVA
Isento                            
6%                                
13%                               
23%      500,00       115,00      

b5El-Processado por programa certificado n.º75/AT.

Os bens/serviços foram colocados à disposição do adquirente em 2020-04-16 * Data/Hora início de transporte: 2020-04-16 às 11:52

Total Líquido               500,00
Total de Descontos 500,00         
Desconto Documento                
Total de IVA                115,00
Total do Documento (EUR)    615,00

IVA      Incidência   Valor do IVA
Isento                            
6%                                
13%                               
23%      500,00       115,00      

b5El-Processado por programa certificado n.º75/AT.

Os bens/serviços foram colocados à disposição do adquirente em 2020-04-16 * Data/Hora início de transporte: 2020-04-16 às 11:52

Total Líquido               500,00
Total de Descontos 500,00         
Desconto Documento                
Total de IVA                115,00
Total do Documento (EUR)    615,00

IVA      Incidência   Valor do IVA
Isento                            
6%                                
13%                               
23%      500,00       115,00      

b5El-Processado por programa certificado n.º75/AT.
```

I need to extract the 4 character code behind "-Processado por programa" but just want 1 match or the 1st match.

Already tried `[^*]+(?=-Processado\spor\sprograma)` and `(.*?)(?=-Processado\spor\sprograma)` but that outputs me 3 matches.

It worked when I removed the `/g` flag but I'm using UiPath Studio's RegEx extractor and I don't know how to remove that flag on that program.

Comment: Try `\A.*(?:(?:\r?\n)(?!\w{4}-Processado\spor\sprograma\b).*)*\r?\n(\w{4})` https://regex101.com/r/fwMEtv/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could match all lines that do not start with 4 word characters and `-Processado por programa` using a negative lookahead.

When you encounter the line that does, capture the first 4 word characters in group 1

```
\A.*(?:\r?\n(?!\w{4}-Processado\spor\sprograma\b).*)*\r?\n(\w{4})
```

**Explanation**

- `\A.*` Assert the position at the start of the string and any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\w{4}-Processado\spor\sprograma\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not `-Processado por programa` directly to the right
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times to match all the lines
- `\r?\n(\w{4})` Match a newline and capture 4 word characters in **group 1**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dOJFjn/1)

Comment: What if there's text behind the 4 char code? I have a different PDF text extraction that has 2 duplicates lines of `Software PHC - YDWL-Processado por programa ` and the goal is to extract the YDWL.

Comment: @LyZ4RD Then you might do it like this https://regex101.com/r/5jJ7Dn/1

Comment: You're the real MVP, thanks again. I might need to hit you up a few more times in the future.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how the Regex would look like if the 4 character code also had other characters such as '/', '*', '.', etc...? I have an instance of an invoice that has the code `CpE/` in it, don't know if the invoice generator may create codes with different characters other than letters and numbers.

Comment: @LyZ4RD You could add the characters that you want to allow https://regex101.com/r/0jL9nb/1 or you could match non whitespace chars excluding the hyphen https://regex101.com/r/Tc4Xkn/1

Comment: I'll go with the second one because these codes may also have numbers on them, feels like that's the right approach. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

```
/(\w{4})-Processado/g
```

is what you are searching for. Look on the image for the Regex tester. It works as intended on exactly 4 chars. When you need help in UiPath to apply it let me know.

[image]

Comment: That outputs 3 matches and it includes the "-Processado" string. I just want the 4 char code.

Comment: Not really. Just take the first group and all is fine. And it does not include the "-Processado" string. Have a try before saying wrong things please.